# How do I re-evaluate my urls.py file after every test within a Django tests.py file?

Tags: django, django-urls, django-testing, django-settings

I have the following construction in my urls.py - it allows me to visually check the format of emails that I send in the browser when I'm developing:

```
urlpatterns = [Various url pattenrns]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [URL Pattern for checking emails]
```

My issue is that when I run my test suite the code only checks `settings.DEBUG` one time - not each time a test or even a `TestCase` runs.

I'm trying to use the `@override_settings` decorator before my tests that apply to the `DEBUG=True` urlpattern with something like:

```
# Most of my tests run fine with Debug=False

@override_settings(DEBUG=True)
# Tests that use the URL pattern for checking emails
```

However, I can't seem to get this to properly toggle the Url pattern between tests...presumably because my urls.py file only loads once for the entire app's tests.

Is there a way to use this type of construction in my urls.py and run my tests? Is there a reason I shouldn't be using this type of conditional in my urls.py?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you say, using `@override_settings(DEBUG=True)` won't work, because Django has already loaded the URL config and evaluated `settings.DEBUG`.

An alternative would be to create another root url config that always includes the debug view.

```
# mysite/debug_urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url
from mysite.urls import urlpatterns as mysite_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = mysite_urlpatterns + [
    url(...),
]
```

Then, in your test, [override the URL config](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/tools/#urlconf-configuration):

```
@override_settings(ROOT_URLCONF='mysite.debug_urls')
```

Comment: Adding to this answer, if you need to add these urls/paths under a namespace you can do something like
urlpatterns = [
    path('',include(([your url list], 'namespace')))
]